# Chaining assisted injected parameters using guice-assistedinject

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

I'm using Guice [Assisted Inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) library to build a factory for me. I currently have it set up like this:

```
class MyObject {
  @Inject public MyObject(@Assisted FirstDep first, @Assisted SecondDep second, ThirdDep third) { /**/ }
}

class FirstDep { /* nothing to see here */ }
class SecondDep {
  @Inject public SecondDep(@Assisted FirstDep first) { /**/ }
}
class ThirdDep { /* nothing to see here either */ }

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(ThirdDep.class);
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(MyObjectFactory.class));
  }
}

interface MyObjectFactory {
  SecondDep createSecond(@Assisted FirstDep first);
  MyObject createMyObject(@Assisted FirstDep first, @Assisted SecondDep second);
}
```

This forces me to explicitly create a `SecondDep` using `factory.createController(first, factory.createSecond(first))`. Is it possible to change my bindings so I can simply do `factory.createController(first)`, which automatically uses the `SecondDep` binding and the argument I passed in?

Comment: I've already tried making MyFactory an abstract class with a method `MyObject createMyObject(@Assisted FirstDep first)` that wraps the two generated methods, but that won't work. Guice requires the factory type to be an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the API you're creating here, especially regarding future extensions or implementations. You evidently have a number of stateful FirstDep instances around, because the SecondDep depends on the particular FirstDep, but a future SecondDep may not depend on that same FirstDep (or any FirstDep at all). The fact that `createMyObject(first)` can be a shorthand to `createMyObject(first, factory.createSecond(first))` is specific to your business case, and I don't think there's a shorthand in Guice to make that assumption.

That said, you have two options. One, you can create a very small helper:

```
// Encapsulate the createMyObject(first) shorthand.
class MyObjectHelper {
  @Inject MyObjectFactory rawFactory;

  MyObject createMyObject(FirstDep first) {
    return rawFactory.createMyObject(first, rawFactory.createSecond(first));
  }
}
```

Or, two, you can use [`@AssistedInject`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/AssistedInject.html) to have Guice effectively overload the constructor:

```
class MyObject {
  // Multiple @AssistedInject constructors, selected based on which parameters
  // are marked with @Assisted.

  @AssistedInject public MyObject(@Assisted FirstDep first,
       SecondFactory secondFactory, ThirdDep third) {
    this(first, secondFactory.createSecond(first), third);
  }

  @AssistedInject public MyObject(@Assisted FirstDep first,
      @Assisted SecondDep second, ThirdDep third) { /**/ }
}

interface SecondFactory {
  // Note that @Assisted annotations are not needed here. Every parameter in
  // these interfaces is for assisted injection, by definition.
  SecondDep createSecond(FirstDep first);
}

interface MyObjectFactory {
  MyObject createMyObject(FirstDep first);
  MyObject createMyObject(FirstDep first, SecondDep second);
}
```

Though it's slightly more verbose to create a separate factory per class, I think you'll find it to be helpful in keeping your classes/factories separate and easy-to-follow, and it neatly avoids a potential circular-reference that I can't remember offhand if Guice supports. I tend to expose my factories as nested interfaces:

```
class SecondDep {
  interface Factory {
    SecondDep create(FirstDep first);
  }

  @Inject public SecondDep(@Assisted FirstDep first) { /**/ }
}
```

...which then lets you find and update `Second.Factory` exactly adjacent to the class it supports.